# Setting default chart parametersin Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a process in MSAccess that culls data then creates a new excel workbook, pushes data out to it then creates a chart in excel.

Once created, the chart is formatted to our preferred look.
That is where things slow down.
We are setting up each individual chart after it has been drawn and with 150 or so charts total, it takes a while.

What I am wondering is, can all of the chart parameters we want be set programmatically as default?
That way, we set once and all charts drawn are in that format from the beginning.

Code used to generate and format charts attached.

Thanks

```
Sub CreateChart(ObjXlWs As Worksheet, K As Integer)
Dim ObjXlChrt As Chart
Dim FixChart As ChartObject
Dim Cntr, J As Integer
Dim ChartNm
Dim xRg As Range

Cntr = K
Set xRg = Range(Split(Cells(1, (((Cntr - 1) * 12 + 1) + 1)).Address, "$")(1) & "4:" & (Split(Cells(1, (((Cntr - 1) * 12 + 10) + 1)).Address, "$")(1) & "26"))

    Set ObjXlChrt = ObjXlWs.ChartObjects.Add(50, 40, 600, 400).Chart
    ObjXlChrt.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    ObjXlChrt.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(ObjXlWs.Name).Range(Split(Cells(1, (((Cntr - 1) * 12 + 2) + 1)).Address, "$")(1) & "66:" & _
        Split(Cells(1, (((Cntr - 1) * 12 + 7) + 1)).Address, "$")(1) & 65 + ObjXlWs.Range(Split(Cells(1, (((Cntr - 1) * 12 + 5) + 1)).Address, "$")(1) & "62").Value), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    ObjXlChrt.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ObjXlWs.Name
    Set FixChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(K)
    With FixChart
        .Top = xRg(1).Top
        .Left = xRg(1).Left
        .Width = xRg.Width
        .Height = xRg.Height
    End With

    With ObjXlChrt
        .HasAxis(xlCategory, xlPrimary) = True
        .HasAxis(xlValue, xlPrimary) = True
        .HasTitle = False
        .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryType = xlCategoryScale
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Date:"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Sheets(ObjXlWs.Name).Range(Split(Cells(1, (((Cntr - 1) * 12 + 1) + 1)).Address, "$")(1) & "60").Value
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = False
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = False
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .HasLegend = False
    End With

   With ObjXlChrt.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels
        .Orientation = xlUpward
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Font.Size = 8
    End With

    With ObjXlChrt.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Font.Size = 8
    End With

    With ObjXlChrt.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Font.Size = 8
    End With

    With ObjXlChrt.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Font.Size = 8
    End With

    ObjXlChrt.PlotArea.ClearFormats

    ObjXlChrt.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Left = 16
    ObjXlChrt.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Top = 300

    ObjXlChrt.PlotArea.Left = 45
    ObjXlChrt.PlotArea.Width = 425
    ObjXlChrt.PlotArea.Top = 21
    ObjXlChrt.PlotArea.Height = 310

    On Error Resume Next

    With ObjXlChrt.SeriesCollection(5)
        .Border.ColorIndex = 1
        .Border.Weight = xlThin
        .Border.LineStyle = xlDot
        .MarkerStyle = xlNone
    End With

    With ObjXlChrt.SeriesCollection(4)
        .Border.ColorIndex = 1
        .Border.Weight = xlThin
        .Border.LineStyle = xlDot
        .MarkerStyle = xlNone
    End With

    With ObjXlChrt.SeriesCollection(3)
        .Border.ColorIndex = 1
        .Border.Weight = xlThin
        .Border.LineStyle = xlDashDot
        .MarkerStyle = xlNone
    End With

    With ObjXlChrt.SeriesCollection(2)
        .Border.ColorIndex = 1
        .Border.Weight = xlThin
        .Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .MarkerStyle = xlSquare
        .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = 2
        .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = 1
        .MarkerSize = 3
    End With

    With ObjXlChrt.SeriesCollection(1)
        .Border.ColorIndex = 1
        .Border.Weight = xlHairline
        .Border.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .MarkerStyle = xlAutomatic
        .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .MarkerSize = 3
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: If this is working code, then [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: Related to your statement, "*can all of the chart parameters we want be set programmatically as default*", you want to set a theme in Excel for a chart?  Without seeing your charts, there could be umpteen ways to work, like making 1 chart with desired format, then copy/paste and modify that copy for each new dataseries.  At the end of the day, more information will be needed.

Comment: Cyril, the code is working right now but bogs down when excel is formatting the chart.  The process is, Access culls data, send to excel, tells excel to draw a chart (with the code above) then formats it; next data set, access culls data, sends to excel (same workbook) draws chart then formats it.
My hope was I could set the chart parameters once in the main function once, then when the sub above is run, all it needs to do is draw the chart.  It would already be in the desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the chart isn't too complicated (and yours isn't), you could make it manually, save it as a template (named "MyChartTemplate" in this example), then apply the template to the chart. You would essentially replace this

```
ObjXlChrt.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
```

with this

```
ObjXlChrt.ApplyChartTemplate Environ("appdata") & _
    "\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\MyChartTemplate.crtx"
```

and then cut out all of that formatting.

Comment: Interesting idea. One additional issue is the process is run from different PCs so that template would need to be on every one.  Unless it could be saved in same spot on the network as the access DB and called from there...  I'll try that and see if it works.

Comment: I think a network admin could put a template into a shared folder somewhere. I don't know how that stuff works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jon Peltier!

Your approach works great.
I saved the format of one of my completed charts as a template and copied that .crtx file to a network location.
Then I simply inserted `ObjXlChrt.ApplyChartTemplate "\\Network\location\MyChHartTemplate.crtx` in my code to replace all the formatting.
Makes future changes easier as well, as all I need to do is create a new template file.

Not the route I thought I needed to take but that's why I posted here to get some other opinions.

Thanks again Jon

Comment: Glad it helped. Could you mark my post as answering your question?